# Error con Classes en Phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser, phaser.io

estoy aprendiendo a usar Phaser, y trabajando con dos escenas. Hasta ahora mi codigo main.js:

```
let config = {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    backgroundColor: 0x000000,
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    scene: [Scene1]
  }


  let game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

y mi codigo de la escena:

```
class Scene1 extends Phaser.Scene{
    constructor(){
        super('loading')
    };

    create() { 
        this.add.text(20,20, 'loading...')
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.scene.start('level1')
          }, 2000);
     }

};
```

Cuando ejecuto, me dice que la clase no esta definida y ademas que 'Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null' No entiendo porque, el archivo js. de la escena esta ubicado antes que el main.js en el html. Si alguno puede orientarme? Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar "modern JS sintax" en tu código, lo que recomiendan en phaser es utilizar el template de parcel.js en tu proyecto. (Primero necesitas instalar node.js y parcel.js).

Clonas el repo en la carpeta de tu proyecto:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/ourcade/phaser3-parcel-template.git
```

Una vez que hayas clonado el repo de parcel, instalas las dependecias:

```
npm install
```

Cuando ya este instalado el template, puedes intentar lo siguiente para main.js:

```
import Phaser from 'phaser'
import Scene1 from './scenes/Scene1'

let config = {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    backgroundColor: 0x000000,
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    scene: [Scene1]
  }

//let game = new Phaser.Game(config);
export default new Phaser.Game(config)
```

Luego, para tu archivo Scene1.js:

```
import Phaser from 'phaser'

export default class Scene1 extends Phaser.Scene
{
    constructor(){
        super('loading')
    };

    create() { 
        this.add.text(20,20, 'loading...')
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.scene.start('level1')
          }, 2000);
     }
}
```

Los archivos de escenas deben estar dentro de la carpeta src->scenes.

Saludos