# Tengo este error en Phaser, ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando Phaser para un proyecto que quiero hacer, intento cargar una imagen desde los assets que tiene Phaser pero me da este error

Primero he puesto en la consola "npm innit -y" y para instalar Phaser he puesto "npm install --save Phaser"

Les dejo también el código que debería mostrar la imagen

```
const game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload() {
    console.log("Cargando")
    this.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png');}

function create() {
    this.add.image(200, 200, "zombie");
    console.log("Cargado")}
```

Comment: El error es que no encuentra el archivo assets/sky.png. Revisa si es el path correcto.

Comment: En el directorio `root` del proyecto debe haber una carpeta `public`, dentro debe haber otra carpeta llamada `assets`, ahí es donde deben estar las imágenes, el código va en otra carpeta llamada `src` que esta igual en el directorio `root` al mismo nivel que `public` ¿Puedes confirmar que tienes la misma estructura en tu directorio `root`? Saludos

Comment: Buenas, no encuentro la carpeta root que dices, en la carpeta solo tengo una carpeta de node_module y el index.html, pero nada más, ¿Puede ser que este en otra carpeta?

Comment: Perdón, debí preguntar primero ¿Estas usando algun template como por ejemplo el template de [parcel](https://github.com/ourcade/phaser3-parcel-template) para tu proyecto? Saludos

Comment: No, solo uso Phaser, el problema que tengo es que no detecta correctamente el path, y no se que pasa porque he instalado correctamente Phaser, ¿sabes en que carpeta puedo verificar el path?

Comment: Intenta crear un nuevo proyecto con el template de [`parcel` para `Phaser`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/351671/error-con-classes-en-phaser?rq=1), ya viene todo configurado (incluido el path y los assets provenientes de phaser), listo para que solo empieces a programar tu juego.